# Verb for "to make optional"

Tags: synonyms

Is there a verb for "to make optional"?  I've searched questoins on this site, thesaurus.com, and looked in my paper thesaurus and dictionary, but don't see anything.

Context for how I plan to use the word is in changelist.  The changelist identifies items that were "added", "removed", "updated" and "made optional."  I'm looking for a single word to replace "made optional."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [on hold] *optionalize*, [to make optional (M-W)](http://i.word.com/idictionary/optionalize)

Comment: It seems like this is not a well-thought-out set.  If I've made an existing entity optional, haven't I just *modified* that entity?  Why single out *modifications* to optionalize? What about *modifications* that make an optional entity mandatory?

Comment: @Jim, yes, technically any of the changes would be a modification.  Symantics of whether 'modified' is an appropriate element of the set, whether there are missing elements or not (given the a tual need of the set) and the intended difference in meaning isn't the question, however :-)

Comment: @Jim: In a software maintenance context, *optionalised* could be a very good fit. You want to know if a feature was *added*, because that may lead to "teething troubles". Later, it may turn out few people have much use for some feature that's still causing problems, so you *remove* or *update* it. But *optionalising* is a cheap way of ensuring the problems go away for everyone who didn't care about the feature anyway. Maybe the diehards will put up with some problems, or maybe you'll *update* it to improve things later. It all sounds reasonable to me - stick with it, atk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best alternative, in this case, is “made optional”.  The only (putative) fault it has is that of not being a single word.  I think it has the advantage of being easier to understand — simpler.  (If you count the space as a letter, it is only one letter longer.)

Comment: All of the answers are great, but considering my readers, this is the one that will be most intuitive.  Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

As Atsuto comments, there's [optionalize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/optionalize), defined by both Merriam-Webster and OED as...

> **optionalize** (BrE **optionalise**) *- to make optional.*

Comment: The OED uses *-ise*? Since when?

Comment: @tchrist: I naturally typed it with BrE spelling in the search box. Got the US spelling for the heading, but...  **optionalize**, v. ... Forms:  19– **optionalise**, 19– optionalize. Etymology: optional adj. + -ize suffix. The OED hasn't gone *completely* "non-native" yet, you know.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be the most common usage, consider **[optioned](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/optioned)**

> to obtain or grant an option on

*To grant an option* means

> the power or liberty to choose

That is what is being done - you have created a situation in which the value can be chosen (or not).